# C# Casting an object returned from invocation and invoking a method on that object

Tags: c#, windows, reflection

I am trying to invoke a method that is within the returned class of another invoked method.

I am trying to call the [GetConnectionCost()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile) method from the `ConnectionProfile` class. The `ConnectionProfile` object was returned by Invoking the `GetInternetConnectionProfile` method from NetworkInformation class.

Below is my code so far:

```
using System.Reflection;

var t = Type.GetType("Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");

var profile = t.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetInternetConnectionProfile").Invoke(null, null);

var cost = profile.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetConnectionCost").Invoke(null, null); //This does not work of course since profile is of type object.
```

I rarely use reflection in my code so I am not an expert in the matter but I am trying to find a way to case the `profile` object and invoke the `GetConnectionCost` method on it.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetInternetConnectionProfile` is static, but `GetConnectionCost` is an instance method.

You need to pass an instance to `Invoke`

Try this:

```
var t = Type.GetType("Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
var profile = t.GetMethod("GetInternetConnectionProfile").Invoke(null, null);
var cost = profile.GetType().GetMethod("GetConnectionCost").Invoke(profile, null);
```

You will still get back an `object`.

You can cast it to `dynamic`

Comment: this is exactly what I did 5 seconds ago. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
var networkInfoType = Type.GetType("Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
            var profileType = Type.GetType("Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
            var profileObj = networkInfoType.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetInternetConnectionProfile").Invoke(null, null);
            dynamic profDyn = profileObj;
            var costObj = profDyn.GetConnectionCost();
            dynamic dynCost = costObj;

            var costType = (NetworkCostType)dynCost.NetworkCostType;
            if (costType == NetworkCostType.Unknown
                    || costType == NetworkCostType.Unrestricted)
            {
                //Connection cost is unknown/unrestricted
            }
            else
            {
                //Metered Network
            }
```